# What's the best way to revert an overwritten native object to original in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, meteor, cordova-plugins, filepicker.io

I've discovered that cordova-plugin-file overwrites the [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object so that it can do some fancy stuff behind the scenes. This is generally fine in Cordova, but I've also discovered that FileStack (another dependency of my project) really needs that native `File` object. I also happen to be using Meteor 1.6 to build my Cordova/Web apps from the same code base.

In my use case, I need to temporarily revert the `File` object back to native while Filestack runs its `.pick()` method.

My current solution is to create a new iFrame, re-assign `File` to the original, remove the iFrame, run Filestack's `.pick()` method, and then reinstate cordova-plugin-file's `File` object to resume normal operations.

```
function setOrigFileObject() 
{
    let iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.src = 'javascript:;';
    iframe.style.display = 'none';

    document.body.appendChild(iframe);

    window.FILE_CORDOVAPLUGINFILE = File;
    window.FILE_NATIVE = iframe.contentWindow.File;
    File = window.FILE_NATIVE;

    document.body.removeChild(iframe);
}
```

This seems to be working pretty well, but I feel like it's not the best solution. For one, adding a whole new browser frame feels pretty hacky for just accessing an object that was already part of scope.

Is there a way to get the native `File` object without creating an iFrame?

Comment: Did you try to store/backup the original `File` object before cordovas plugins kick in? Something like `const FileOriginal = File;` and as soon as cordova fires its ready event you could store `const FileCordova = File;`. This should give you access to both variants. **Curious**.

Comment: I thought about that, but I don't know if I can run anything in advance of the Cordova plugins' initialization without creating a race condition (or forking the plugin, which might cost me maintainability). Do you know how I could do that predictably?

Comment: One way to do it would probably be to load the `cordova.js` only after you're done with your preparation. So you save FileOriginal, then add the script tag which loads cordova.js to the page.

Comment: Hmm. I'll look into that. This is complicated a bit by the fact that I'm running in Meteor and may not have that much control over runtime, but I'll look into it and see if I can hook in before cordova.js and/or the plugins initialize.

Comment: This won't work for my particular use case (without forking the Meteor repository), so it looks like I may just stick with the iFrame. Setting this at runtime, potentially in a `<script>` tag within the document's `<head>` above any dependencies, would work in pretty much any other case, though!